# grep string that start with prefix

Tags: grep

I would like to display the list of icons used in a whole directory without duplicates, for example I have:

```
<span class="icon icon-test"></span> (in test1.html)
<span class="icon icon-wrench"></span> (in wrench.html)
<span class="icon icon-test"></span> (in test3.html)
```

Output wanted:

```
test
wrench
```

So far I tried somethink like that:

```
grep -onr 'icon-.* "$' .
```

Comment: do you have `grep -P` available?

Comment: @pLumo thank you for your edit, and nope does not look like grep -P is available

Answer (score 3):

With `grep -P`:

```
grep -Phro 'icon-\K[^" ]+' . | sort -u
```

without `grep -P`:

```
grep -hro 'icon-[^" ]\+' . | cut -d- -f2 | sort -u
```

Explanation:

- `-P` Use Perl Compatible Regex (PCRE) instead of Basic Regex (BRE)
- `-h` Do not print filenames
- `-r` Run recursively on all files
- `-o` Output only the match instead of whole lines
- `[^" ]+` Match 1 or more characters that are not a double quote or a space, you could change that to e.g. `[a-z]+` if you know that the names are all lower case characters from a-z. Note: for `BRE` you need to escape the quantifier: `\+`.
- `| cut -d- -f2` remove `icon-` from grep output. (There are many ways to achieve that, if you want to stick with `grep`, you may use `grep -o '\w\+$'`).
- `| sort -u` Sort output and remove duplicates.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and explanation ! I tried grep -hro 'icon-[^" ]\+' | sed 's/icon-//' | sort -u -> grep: warning: recursive search of stdin

Comment: try again... my `grep` implementation implicitly uses the current working dir if none is added, maybe yours is not doing that, so you need to add the `.` ...

Comment: Much better, thank you ! Do you know how can I target html and php files only ? Currently the grep also display some result from css files

Comment: add this to `grep`:  `--include="*.html" --include="*.php"`